# How do I get object type and passed it on to ObjectContent

Tags: c#

I decided to create a function to encapsulate many lines of codes into 1 line of code. So hence this example script.  What I could not get to work is get the class's `Type` and pass it on to `ObjectContent`'s parameter for it to work.

Take a look at `xmlObjectType` variable in `ObjectContent<xmlObjectType>(....)` and the `System.Type` assignment to `xmlObjectType` using `GetType()` on the passed-in paramater object.  What do you guys do to get the actual object type for this to work with `ObjectContent`?

```
public class XmlError
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
public class XmlBuilderTools 
{
   public HttpResponseMessage ErrorResponse(object parmXmlErrorLayout)
   {
       HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMsg = new HttpResponseMessage();
       Type xmlObjectType = parmXmlErrorLayout.GetType();

       httpResponseMsg.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
       httpResponseMsg.Content = new ObjectContent<xmlObjectType>(parmXmlErrorLayout, new XmlMediaTypeFormatter());
   }
}

//Acutual scripts...
XmlBuilderTools xmlBuilderTools = new XmlBuilderTools();
XmlError xmlError = new XmlError();

xmlError.Message = "Foo";

return xmlBuilderTools.ErrorResponse(xmlError);
```

`Edited` - Found a workaround to this problem.  You do not have to invoke it, instead do use other object overloading that works.  Me Duh!

```
 httpResponseMsg.Content = new ObjectContent(parmXmlErrorLayout.GetType(), parmXmlErrorLayout, new CustomXmlFormatter());
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply can't do that. You have to use reflection instead.

```
MethodInfo method = yourInstance.GetType().GetMethod("ObjectContent").MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { xmlObjectType });
method.Invoke(this, new object[] { parmXmlErrorLayout, new XmlMediaTypeFormatter() });
```

Otherwise pass the type as a parameter to method too.

Comment: What the full namespace to GetType() for "GetType().GetMethod("foo").MakeGenericMethod()"?