# Invoke ObjectContent in a static function result in "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

Fresh coming in from accepted answer at [How do I get object type and passed it on to ObjectContent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27408183/how-do-i-get-object-type-and-passed-it-on-to-objectcontent#27408707), which was about passing in `class` type to newly created function having `ObjectContent` object in it to work.

My next step is to convert it to static class/functions.  To the best of my ability, I'm getting exception error when assigning `type.GetMethod("ObjectContent", ...)` to `methodInfo` variable.

The error message is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

What seems to be the problem here with `type.GetMethod("ObjectContent", ...)`?  What's the workaround to this problem?

```
public class XmlError
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
public static class XmlBuilderTools 
{
    public static HttpResponseMessage ErrorResponse(object parmXmlErrorLayout)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMsg = new HttpResponseMessage();
        Type type = parmXmlErrorLayout.GetType();  //typeof(parmXmlErrorLayout);

        System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod("ObjectContent", (System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy));
        returnHttpResponseMessage.Content = (HttpContent)methodInfo.Invoke(null, new object[] { parmXmlErrorLayout, new XmlMediaTypeFormatter() });

        httpResponseMsg.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
    }
}

public class Foo()
{
   public HttpResponseMessage FooFoo()
   {
       //Acutual scripts...
       XmlError xmlError = new XmlError();

       xmlError.Message = "Foo";

       return XmlBuilderTools.ErrorResponse(xmlError);
   }
}
```

Originally this would work in non-static class/object

```
returnHttpResponseMessage.Content = new ObjectContent<XmlError>(xmlError, new CustomXmlFormatter());
```

Comment: Just edited the post to include error messages above.  The error message is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Comment: show the ObjectContent method, you sure that is a method and not a property?

Comment: The MSDN showed it is a class name.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.objectcontent%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

Comment: ok, that is the class, but you are getting the method from an instance of whatever `parmXmlDataLayout` is...  what is the type at run time?  You defined it as object...

Comment: I fixed the posting error.  It should be parmXmlErrorLayout instead.

Comment: so what is the type?  Your code will only work if the class/type has a static method named `ObjectContent()`  Show the code where this static method is defined, that is the ONLY way your code will work.

Comment: Hmm.   ObjectContent is part of .NET framework and that object is done as instanstantion (instance of object).  :-/

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Comment: It's the internal compoment inside the closed source .NET framework that returned null and it failed to tell us why it is null cuz we can't access closed source to find out why.  I found a workaround to it by using a different overloading `ObjectContent` object.  By the way, you're not a helpful person for not reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have

```
 Type type = parmXmlDataLayout.GetType();  //typeof(parmXmlDataLayout);
```

but you pass in

```
object parmXmlErrorLayout
```

so shouldnt it be

```
Type type = parmXmlErrorLayout.GetType();  //typeof(parmXmlErrorLayout);
```

and if not then you need to define an instance of parmXmlDataLayout as I do not see that anywhere in your code. hence why you would get the error from type.Gettype, type is probably null

`Edited by fletchsod - Alternative workaround to the problem`

Instead of invoking, appearantly there's another overloading to `ObjectContent` that works great.  Me Duh!  Too many of same objects I haven't worked with before.  The solution to the problem is

```
foo.Content = new ObjectContent(parmXmlErrorLayout.GetType(), parmXmlErrorLayout, new CustomXmlFormatter());
```

Comment: I fixed the posting error.

Comment: ok, on that note, do you check to see if parmXmlErrorLayout is null or type is null after calling parmXmlErrorLayout.GetType()?

Comment: both `type` and `parmXmlErrorLayout` contains data.  No nullable value is found.    The `ObjectContent` is a class/object found in MSDN documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.objectcontent%28v=vs.118%29.aspx .

Comment: as you stated in your comment above its not a static class.  Remove System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static and replace with System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance and remove the System.Reflection.BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy as this is also used for static methods.  It looks like you are looking for the constructor which is a public method but is not static.

Comment: Nice.  I didn't realize there's "Instance" object.   I tried that and still error.  Upon further debugging, what I found is `type` contains data but `type.GetMethod(...)` returned null so the variable `methodInfo` end up as null.  That explained why I got exception error but why does `GetMethod` returned null?

Comment: does parmXmlErrorLayout inherit from ObjectContent? if not then you probably want something like typeOf(ObjectContent).GetMethod("ObjectContent", (System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance| System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public));   oh and sorry John hosed you by marking this as a duplicate, I thought it was total BS he did.

Comment: Yes I agree with you about total BS he did.  That still doesn't explain why `GetMethod()` is nullable cuz it was done internally inside the .NET framework which I have no control over.   Not happy about it but that's called democracy.  Let you know very recently I found a different workaround to the problem after many trials & errors.   I amended your answer with the workaround I found and I'm gonna accept your answer for all of the trouble we went through.

Comment: While my amended answer is being peer reviewed.   The workaround I made is `foo.Content = new ObjectContent(parmXmlErrorLayout.GetType(), parmXmlErrorLayout, new CustomXmlFormatter());`